# Formula for ranking based on two factors

Tags: math

This is a math question really, I'm trying to give a rank to users based on two things: the time it takes them to do something and a percentage.

Basically, the shortest time + the highest percentage gives the best rank. On the opposite, the longest time + the lowest percentage will give the worst rank.

I'm trying to find out a formula for this. Ideally it would return x points and then I'll sort the users based on the points they each have.

Example (totally random):
- user has 94% and 2.3 seconds: he will get a ranking point of 123
- user has 56% and 2.3 seconds: he will get a ranking point of 87
- user has 56% and 5.1 seconds: he will get a ranking point of 73

OPTION: the percentage should weight more than the time in the final result

What a good formula would be ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two things to consider:

1. Impact of each of your factors
2. Cross-over impact between factors

**Impact**

This basically scores each of the two factors separately but normalises them and weighs them.

```
score = (factor_A_impact * player_score_of_factor_A / maximum_score_of_factor_A) + (factor_B_impact * player_score_of_factor_B / maximum_score_of_factor_B);
```

**Cross-over**

This adds a crossover effect. In effect making score A more important then B because it affects the end value of B. The crossover factor is ranging from 1 to 0. 0 is no modulation what so ever of the b impact and 1 is complete modulation of the B factor by the A Factor. You can add as many factors as you want to this and chain them up in various complicated ways.

```
crossOverFactor = 0.2
score_factor_A_normalised = (player_score_of_factor_A / maximum_score_of_factor_A);
score_factor_B_normalised = (player_score_of_factor_B / maximum_score_of_factor_B);

score_B_crossOveredByA = score_factor_B_normalised*(1-crossOverFactor) + (score_factor_A_normalised*crossOverFactor*score_factor_B_normalised);
score = (score_factor_A_normalised*factor_A_impact) + (score_B_crossOveredByA * factor_B_impact);
```

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. My terrible lack of math knowledge makes it hard for me to understand everything though. Especially the crossOverFactor. I'll try to figure it out.

Comment: If you understand how to normalise the scores, and go from there, then you can do almost anything you want. I would advise you to do a spreadsheet where two columns are the two factors, and then fill in enough rows so that it gives a good representation of different outcomes + some extremes. Then the next columns you make can be tests of various ways to score it. That'll give you a playground to test it in.

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify what the end-goal is. It can depend on what, according to you is more important- percentage or time. Then, you can assign points, e.g if there are 25 data points,

```
stepValue = 100/25 # = 4
percentagePoints = ((25+1) - percentageRank)*stepValue
```

This will score the highest % 100, the next 96, then 92 etc. Do the same for time.

Take a simple average/sum of the two scores, or a weighted average if you decide one is more important than the other (and manage to decide which one is *how much more* important than the other).

Comment: I have edited the question because I, indeed, need to give more importance to the percentage - I do not understand the "25 data points" here though.